# Is using typeid on a forward declared type undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards

Am I reading the standard correctly in `5.2.8.3: ... If the type of the
expression is a class type, the class shall be completely-defined.`  If the type is not "completely-defined" does that mean the following program is undefined?

foo.cpp:

```
struct foo
{
  virtual void a(){}
};

struct bar : foo
{
  virtual void a(){}
};

bar abar;

foo& get_some_foo()
{
  return abar;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

struct foo;

foo& get_some_foo();

int main()
{
  foo& a_ref_foo(get_some_foo());

  std::cout << "a_ref_foo typeid name: " << typeid(a_ref_foo).name() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

MSVC10 outputs: `a_ref_foo typeid name: struct foo'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When I compile your code with:

```
g++ foo.cpp main.cpp -o main
```

I get:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:12:52: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct foo’
main.cpp:4:8: error: forward declaration of ‘struct foo’
```

That agrees with my interpretation of the standard, that you can't apply `typeid` to an incomplete type — and `a_ref_foo` is of an incomplete type, since the full definition of the type `foo` is not visible. `main.cpp` (with the lines I added) is ill-formed, and a diagnostic is required.

**Update :**

I've reproduced the issue with Visual Studio 2010 Express.  Even with language extensions disabled, this trivial program:

```
#include <typeinfo>

struct foo;

int main()
{
  typeid (foo);
  return 0;
}
```

compiled with no diagnostic messages.  With gcc 4.7, I get:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:7:14: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct foo’
main.cpp:3:8: error: forward declaration of ‘struct foo’
```

The same rule:

> If the type of the expression is a class type, the class shall be
>   completely-defined.

appears in the 1998, 2003, and 2012 versions of the ISO C++ standard.

Looks like a bug in Visual Studio. (If somebody would like to report this to Microsoft, go ahead.)

Comment: In this case, the use of "shall" means it's ill-formed, because this is a diagnosable rule (i.e., it's not said that "no diagnostic is required" and is not explicitly described as undefined behaviour).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Thanks, I've updated the answer. (The C standard, with which I'm more familiar, uses "shall" differently; a violation of a "shall" that's not in an explicit *constraint* make the program's behavior undefined. The C++ rules are covered in section 1.4, "Implementation compliance".)

Comment: Your assumption about includes was correct.  Sorry about that.  I also just tried on gcc and got the same errors.  Its interesting MSVC 10 with w4 doesn't even warn.

Comment: @Zac: Yes, and I just reproduced it myself with a much simpler test case, even with language extensions disabled. The same rule appears in the 1998, 2003, and 2011 versions of the C++ standard.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the program is ill-formed (rather than causing undefined behavior).

If you wonder *why*, then you should consider that `typeid` is a single operator, but it has completely different semantics for polymorphic types than for non-polymorphic types. In particular, if `foo` is polymorphic (has at least one virtual function, then `typeid` will yield a reference to the `type_info` object for the *actual type* (in this case `bar`) while if the type does not have any virtual function then it will return a reference to the `type_info` object for the *static* type of the expression (in this case `foo`).

For the compiler to generate the appropriate code, the compiler must *know* at the place where `typeid` is used which of the two cases applies. If the type is incomplete, that information is not present for the compiler.

Comment: You're why makes sense - thats what I was assuming, the compiler only sees a non-polymorphic type. I ran into this behavior and was digging through the standard trying to figure out what it meant. Thanks.

Comment: @Zac: The compiler should have rejected your code. It is not Undefined Behavior, but rather an ill-formed program that is trivially diagnosable by the compiler.

Comment: That distinction (dynamic vs. static type) doesn't apply to uses of typeid where the argument is a type name, which GCC at least also flags as an error, e.g.: struct Foo; const std::type_info &fooType = typeid(Foo);

Comment: this should have been the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your program is completely correct because functions  `get_some_foo` and `bar` are globals.  So `bar` is completely defined, but if you define a variant of `bar` in `main.cpp`, then use it as a parameter in typeid , or error occurs when compiling.

Comment: In the translation unit where `main` is defined, the type `foo` **is** incomplete.